# Error: The argument type 'Future<Widget>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I saw other people is able to do this in their code but why am i having an error when i try to implement this?

Please help as i do not know what is going on

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: await getLandingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my code for the Future getLandingPage()

```
Future<Widget> getLandingPage() async {
  return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && (!snapshot.data.isAnonymous)) {
        return TransportMenu();
      }

      return LoginPage();
    },
  );
}
```

the error that came out is this

> Error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.

**UPDATE**
After fixing the error, another error in `TransportMenu` popped, this is the code for that

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transportdemo/main.dart';
import 'package:transportdemo/personal_info.dart';
import 'package:transportdemo/sign_in.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';
import 'cluster_list.dart';
import 'personal_info.dart';

String cluster = 'HEART';
String preselected = 'HEART';
final listOfClusters = ['HEART', 'VOICE', 'MOVE', 'MIND', 'FORCE', 'STRIKE'];

class TransportMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransportMenuState createState() => _TransportMenuState();
}

bool theme = true;

class _TransportMenuState extends State<TransportMenu> {
  _displayDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Select Your Cluster'),
            content: DropdownButtonFormField(
              value: preselected,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Clusters',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                    ),
              items: listOfClusters.map((String value) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: new Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  preselected = newValue;
                cluster = newValue;
                });
              },validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please Select a cluster';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
              isExpanded: false,
             ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: Text('CONFIRM'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getThingsOnStartup().then((value) {
      _displayDialog(context);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future _getThingsOnStartup() async {
    await Future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: theme ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark(),
        home: DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    Switch(
                      activeColor: Colors.white,
                      value: theme,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          theme = value;
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                  title: Text('Welcome, ' +
                      name +
                      " " +
                      role +
                      '\nTo CYC Kuchai Transport App'),
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Personal Info',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Transport\n  Request',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Settings',
                        icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                body: TabBarView(
                  children: [PersonalInfo(), ClusterMenu(), MyApp()],
                ))));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include details about the new error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the async modifier and the Future. you do not need them in this case

```dart
Widget getLandingPage() {
  return StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
    stream: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData && (!snapshot.data.isAnonymous)) {
        return TransportMenu();
      }

      return LoginPage();
    },
  );
}
```

also, remove the await from your `MaterialApp`

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: getLandingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked because you were not performing any asynchronous operations in the `getLandingPage()` so you do not need it to be a `Future<Widget>` but only a `Widget`. If you notice, there is no `await` in the `getLandingPage()`.

Comment: ohh.. but when i launched the app, it says an error page, invalid arguments

Comment: error wasnt in the codes, it happens after i clicked debug, this is the screenshot http://prnt.sc/tr290e let me know if u need additional info\

Comment: There should be error in your console, paste those. and also, you should try restarting the app

Comment: The following ArgumentError was thrown building TransportMenu(dirty, state: _TransportMenuState#63c8c):
Invalid argument(s)

Comment: It seems there's something wrong with your `TransportMenu` menu page. You can try debuting by replacing `getLandingPage()` in the MaterialApp with `TransportMenu()` and lets see the error that comes

Comment: it still presists, thats odd though.. i dont recall changing anything in `TransportMenu` .. i will update the whole `TransportMenu` page in the original question

Comment: Does it bring out anymore errors or information about the error?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tr2hm0 i put it in a screenshot cuz i dont think i can copy all those

Comment: COuld be the dialog, comment out _getThingsOnStartup().then((value) {
      _displayDialog(context);
    }); in your `initState` and let's see if that fixes it

Comment: nope, nothing happened after commenting out the codes related to the dialog

Comment: I have a few theories, 1. could be the `MyApp()` in your `TabView`. 2. could be because you have a `MaterialApp` in your `TransportMenu` while there's also a `MaterialApp` in your `MyApp`. Change the Material app in your `TransportMenu` to a Scaffold